# Shopping cart for selling customized electronic membership cards (delivered by email)

Tags: web-apps, shopping-cart

I am looking for a web app (or web-based service that can be integrated with an existing app) that would provide this functionality:

1. Allows customizing the sold digital product on a per-user basis,
   such as writing customers name, membership ID, and an expiration
   date to a predefined image (some common image format such as png,
   jpg, or gif). In this case functionality to allow the buyer to
   customize the product is not needed.
2. Can handle processing the payment, customizing the product, and
   emailing the product to the buyer automatically (i.e. without
   requiring a web admin to approve or process orders on the back-end).
   About the emailing it is also acceptable if it, instead of sending
   the email, is able to integrate with third-party apps (e.g.
   MailChimp) for the email handling.
3. (Optional) would come with an integration to some different payment
   gateways.

I would not expect this to be a free app/service so the price or monthly cost is not particularly important.

An alternative solution composed of separate apps/services could also be accepted as answer, if it is able to provide above functionality.

Comment: What you are asking sounds more like the customization of a service, than a software per se. For instance, the item 1 can be done with a simple script and imagemagick, a free software. To my knowledge, ANY software for online shopping will do what you ask, but will require some programming. You need to give more info, like: do  you pretend or not to self-host that, you pretend to put that on your own site or not, etc.